# Adal Interceptor doesnt return the call back to the ajax call

Tags: adal.js

I am using the AdalJs in my angular js application, when I access the external API the adal interceptor checks if my resource is present in the session storage and makes the acquire token call if it doesn't exist in the session storage. Once the token is retrieved it updates the session storage with the new token for that resource, but the control is not returned back to the ajax call and the caller gets stuck in there.If I refresh the page again I am able to get the data from the eternal API as it is now able to get the data from the session storage. Am I missing something here?

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'config', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, config, adalProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController',
            })
            .when('/userInfo', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/userInfo.html',
                controller  : 'userInfoController',
                requireADLogin: true,
            })
            .when('/apiData', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/apiData.html',
                controller  : 'apiDataController',
                requireADLogin: true,
            }).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });


    adalProvider.init({
        instance: config.instance, 
        tenant: config.tenant, //adfs
        clientId: config.clientId,
        extraQueryParameter: config.extraQueryParameter, 
        endpoints : config.endpoints,
        redirectUri : config.redirectUri,
    },
        $httpProvider);
    }]);

    sampleApp.controller('apiDataController', function($scope, adalAuthenticationService, $http, config) {
    $scope.message = 'Fetching data from the API:';
    $scope.userInfo = adalAuthenticationService.userInfo;

        var client = $http({
            method: 'GET', 
            url: config.apiURL, 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }

        });

        client.then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.message = "Data is fetched from the API with Access Token";

            $scope.apiData = data.data;
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            $scope.message = data.data;
        });

});
```

Comment: Could you please include code snippets which could help reproduce this issue ?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet here.

Comment: I still can't reproduce your problem , i download the code sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp) and modify the `userDataCtrl.js` with your code and it works . You could find my test project from [here](https://github.com/yunan2016/TodoSPA) . You could also provide your test project if possible to help us reproduce that .

Comment: Thanks for your sample it helped me to resolve, I took the adal.js and adal-angular from your sample and it worked.Later I figured out that there was version mismatch between Adal and adal-angular version in my sample. (Adal v1.0.13,  Angular v1.0.0)

Comment: i write a reply base on your feedback , you could mark it as answer which may helps others who meet same problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, when we integrating Azure AD into an AngularJS single page app , we need to make sure adal.js and Angular.js are the same version , version mismatch may cause potential problems .

Comment: Yes that matching the versions of both the files resolved the issue. Thanks for your help.